# check system if font exists python (OS agnostic)

Tags: python

I have seen a few answers regarding how to retrieve the font list via different modules, such at matlab, or Tkinter, but I don't want to include a huge library like those to solve my current problem of just retrieving this list.

**Background:** I am working on an html to pdf system, and it runs on both OSX and ubuntu servers, so the answer can't be just a single os implementation

**TL;DR:** are there any light modules/libraries in python that will allow me to retrieve the list of existing fonts on the hosting server?

Comment: Not a python utility, but on ubuntu, `fc-list` will list available fonts.

Comment: tkinter is a built-in module, just use it

Comment: If I include that module is it still pretty lightweight? at this point I do not want to weigh down our package, but if it's the only way to solve this problem I will do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a script to verify if Helvetica Neue and Courier are installed:

```
def verify_fonts_are_installed_for_statements():
    import subprocess
    from os import path
    potential_locations = [
        '/usr/bin/fc-list',
        '/usr/sbin/fc-list',
        '/usr/local/sbin/fc-list',
        '/usr/local/bin/fc-list',
    ]
    valid_path = None
    for file_path in potential_locations:
        if path.exists(file_path):
            valid_path = file_path
            break
    if valid_path is None:
        raise IOError('could not find fc-list to verify fonts exist.')

    cmd = [valid_path]
    output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

    if 'Helvetica Neue' not in output:
        raise FontNotInstalledException('Helvetica Neue')
    if 'Courier' not in output:
        raise FontNotInstalledException('Courier')

    log.debug('Courier and Helvetica Neue were found to be installed.')
```